# Get all drinks from database with their ingredients in json fromat - PHP - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have created a simple DB with mySQL :

1. Table - Drinks : id, name, ...
2. Table - Ingredients: id, name, ...
3. Table - Drink_Ingredients: drink_id, ingredient_id

I want to make a query and get a json like the bellow format:

```
[{
  "id": "000a1",
  "name": "Mojito",
  "ingredients": [{
      "id": "000i1",
      "name": "Lime"
  }, {
      "id": "000i2",
      "name": "Bacardi"
  }]

 }, {
  "id": "000d2",
  "name": "Cuba Libre",
  "ingredients": [{
      "id": "000i3",
      "name": "Rum"
  }, {
      "id": "000i4",
      "name": "Cola"
  }]
```

}]

How can I accomplish that? Should I make a request to get all drinks first and then iterate through all drinks and make another request inside to get their ingredients? also do I need the corresponding PHP objects to handle the data and then print the JSON or it does'n matter?

Comment: *"Should I make a request to get all drinks first and then iterate through all drinks and make another request inside to get their ingredients? also do I need the corresponding PHP objects to handle the data and then print the JSON"* ... yes and no.

Comment: you can write a Join query to achieve this result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first get the data what you need:

```
$drinks = array();
$i = 0;
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM drinks";
//conn is your database connect variable
$result = $conn->query($sql);
foreach($result as $v=>$row){
   $drinks[$i]['name'] = $row["name"];
   $drinks[$i]['id'] = $row["id"];
   $drinks[$i]['ingredients'] = array();
   $j = 0;
   $sql2 = "SELECT ingredients_id, name FROM drink_Ingredients INNER JOIN ingredients on drink_Ingredients.ingredients_id=ingredients.id";
   $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
   foreach($result2 as $v2=>$row2){
       $drinks[$i]['ingredients'][$j]['id'] = $row2["ingredients_id"];
       $drinks[$i]['ingredients'][$j]['name'] = $row2["name"];
       $j++;
   }
   $i++
}
```

After you have the drinks array, you need to make the json:

```
$json = json_encode($drinks);
```

That's all :)

Comment: It works great! You save me a lot of hours. THANK YOU Robert!